# Cygwin putting down older versions of some files

Tags: cygwin

A beginner's Cygwin question here - I'd like to install a newer version of Cygwin (the latest, which is 1.7.9) on a few Windows 2008 Server boxes which currently have rather an old version (1.5.25).  I need to do an offline, silent install, and I'm currently deciding whether to do some sort of manually produced list of changed/added/removed files, or just replace the old install with the new.  The install is quite big (80 odd megs), so just doing the differences might make sense here.  It looks like there is nothing in the way of registry servering or so on required to install Cygwin -you just copy the files somewhere, add it the the path and you're good to go.

One problem, though, is that looking at what's changed between old and new reveals that some of the files the most recent install has used are actually older versions that what we've already got.  Ie  cygintl-8.dll, envsubst.exe, gettext.exe.  Surely you can't mix and match versions?

I'd appreciate it if a more experienced Cygwin user could reply with a few hints as to the best approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always an official `config.ini` file that lists a recommended version of each package, plus often both newer and older versions than the recommended one. When you do an installation with `setup.exe`, you can elect to use the bleeding edge versions for some or all of the packages. Perhaps your 1.5.25 version was installed with all the bleeding-edge packages, and the 1.7.9 just accepted the defaults. It's not unlikely that some sets of old/current/new packages hadn't changed between those two cygwin versions.

In general, you *can* mix and match a lot of things, just as you can on Linux. You can't take an old version of the core `cygwin1.dll` library and expect new packages to run against it; but not all the packages have to be in lockstep.

Comment: Thanks.  But where is config.ini?

Comment: It's the first thing that `setup.exe` downloads when it runs; it how `setup.exe` knows about what the current release entails. It might actually be named `setup.ini`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was setup.ini.